# Probability of exceeding a value with a given expectation and variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, variance

A factory produces $n$ items a week and is a random variable with expectation $50$ and variance $25$ what can be said about the probability that this weeks production will exceed $75$?
The question then asks;  What can be said about the probability that this week’s production will be between $40$ and $60$?

I understand the formulas for $E(x) = \frac { (n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + ... + n_m)} {m}$

and $ Var(x) = E(x^2) - E (x)^2 $

I just cant figure out how to use these two values to use them to answer the questions? Any help or explanations will be much appreciated

Comment: What inequalities are you familiar with?

Comment: Do you know the central limit theorem? Chebyshev/Markov inequality?

Comment: If you can assume normality, you don't need to use inequalities. In R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF, code `1 - pnorm(75, 50, 5)` returns $2.866516e−07,$ which is essentially $0.$ and code `diff(pnorm(c(40,60), 50, 5))` returns $0.9544997.$ // With printed standard normal CDF tables, start with standard score $z=(X−50)/5,$ where $μ=50,σ=\sqrt{25}=5.$ Due to rounding, tables will give answers correct to about three places, which is good enough for most practical purposes. // Compare with results from inequalities, in @tommik's Answer. (+1) // Parts of this can be solved using the Empirical Rule

Answer (score 2):

1. you can use Markov's inequality

$$\mathbb{P}[X\ge 75]\le \frac{50}{75}$$

2. Invoking Chebishev's inequality you get

$$\mathbb{P}\{|X-50|<10\}|\ge1- \frac{25}{10^2}=1-0.25$$